# Keep Showing Previous Intent when click back button

Tags: android, android-intent, user-interface, android-activity

I have an issues when clicking the back button. It keeps going to the previous activity. The user can logged in to use the app. But the problem is when user logs out, and click the back button, it will show the 'logged in' panel page. And if user wants to quit the app, they will have to go through a multiple back clicks. This is not how I want it to be.

Of course I can use the menu and have an option for user to quit the app, but I do not want to use that approach because it is not a commonly use method. It is not very good because normally users will click back to the first page and prompted if they want to quit.

How do I solve the intent problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you never want the activity accessible via the back stack, you modify its entry in AndroidManifest.xml like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myDomain.myApp.MyActivity"
    android:label="My Activity"
    android:noHistory="true" >
</activity>
```

If you just want to make sure the previous activity doesn't show in the back stack, you can add a handler in each activity that calls finish() and then call it from the current activity.

Previous Activity:

```
public void goAway()
{
    finish();
}
```

Current Activity:

```
previousActivity.goAway();
```

Of course, you'll need a reference to the previous activity in the current activity.

Comment: How do I create a reference? Is it if my previous activity has a java file named HelloWorld.java, I call out HelloWorld.goAway();?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the back stack and clear it only when the user logs out or presses back button from the logged out screen, the following can be done.

1: start each activity by calling `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)` with the same `REQUEST_CODE`

2: override `onActivityResult()` in each `Activity` and add the following code piece,

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    setResult(OK);
    finish();
}
```

3: When the user logs out or when back key is pressed from the logged out screem, do the following

```
setResult(OK);
finish();
```

This will ensure that all the activities in the back stack are cleared after the user logs out.